# Getting error for the new release branch in Jenkins

Tags: git, jenkins

I have created the new release branch for deploying changes in the development environment to the testing environment in the git, but in Jenkins, it is showing an error like "ERROR: Version 1.25.0-rc.1 already exists". But when I'm trying this 1.25.0-rc.1 in the tracker version of tsta my changes are not getting replicated.